# Api ipv6 kernel 4.6

Tags: c, linux

Estoy trabajando sobre un aplicación hecha con Netlink en Linux kernel 2.6
Y quiero hacerlo funcionar para un linux kernel 4.6
Estoy teniendo problemas con la función ioctl.

Antes de correr mi aplicación, genero un conexión ad-hoc (por interface wireless) que me impone una dirección ipv6 global link estática 2001::d/64 y luego tenemos una dirección ipv6 link local (fe80::9eaf:1ea3.....) impuesto por el sistema (como un DHCP en ipv4)
Entonces quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego al correr la aplicacion, se utiliza inicialmente como paquete de control la dirección ipv6 link local (fe80::9eaf:1ea3.....), pero luego se lo borra de la interfaz porque la aplicación no necesita de esa dirección. Es decir que se aplica la siguiente función:

ioctl(fd, SIOCDIFADDR, &ifr6)

La función borra el link local (fe80::9eaf:1ea3.....) de la interfaz wireless, y luego se crea otra link local (fe80::ba60:e8c6...) como indica en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es un problema, ya que hay paquetes ip que son generados con esta dirección y no debería ser asi.

Por lo que estuve viendo, el nuevo servicio NetworkManager que funciona en las versiones mas recientes de Ubuntu 16.10 o 16.04, que siempre impone una dirección ipv6 link local al borrar otra (como ocurrió recién)

Se podrá hacer otra cosa? Luego de llegado el momento, que solo me figure la dirección global link 2001::d para trabajar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Recién explique en concreto cual es el problema. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Supongo que no podrás desconectar el `NetworkManager` pero ... ¿ No sería posible forzarlo a *ignorar* la interfaz en cuestión ?

Comment: Muchas gracias.